# ¿Cómo hago para que no hayan elementos repetidos en un ArrayList?

Tags: java, array, netbeans, arraylist, parametros

tengo un problema y es que tengo en un `Arraylist` nombre,edad,etc. pero quiero que no se repita la identificación, he intentado con `contains` pero no me sirve o algo estoy haciendo mal si alguien me puede ayudar estaría genial, gracias.

```
public class AutoMovilesMejorado  {
    
    public BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    private Cliente cliente; 
    
    ArrayList<Cliente> listaCliente = new ArrayList();


        private void ingresarCliente() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos separados por '&':(Nombre, Edad, Identificacion, Presupuesto)");
        String texto = br.readLine();
        String [] dato = texto.split("&");
        String nombre = dato[0];
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
        int identificacion = Integer.parseInt(dato[2]);
        double presupuesto = Double.parseDouble(dato[3]);
        if (dato.length==4) {
        Cliente clienteNuevo = new Cliente(nombre,edad,identificacion,presupuesto, false);
        if (edad >= 18 ) {
                if (listaCliente.contains(identificacion)==true) { //aqui como hago ayua
                  System.out.println("Identificacion repetida");  
                } else{
                    listaCliente.add(clienteNuevo);
                    System.out.println("Usuario Ingresado Correctamente " + "\n" + listaCliente);
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Debe ser mayor de edad");
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Datos mal ingresados");
            ingresarCliente();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Si no quieres elementos repetidos, una lista no es la mejor estructura para almacenarlos, te conviene más un `Set`, por ejemplo implementado con un `HashSet`. Luego para que el `Set` se encargue por sí mismo de no meter repetidos, sobreescribes los métodos `equals` y `hashCode` de la clase `Cliente` para que determine que un elemento es igual si el valor de `identificacion` es el mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías crear un método que te busque si ya ese cliente existe

```
private boolean ExisteCliente(Cliente cliente)
{
   boolean existe = false;

   for(int i = 0; i < listaCliente.size(); i++)
   {
      if(listaCliente.get(i).identificacion == cliente.identificacion)
      {
         existe = true;
         break;
      }
   }

   return existe;
}
```

Este método recorre todos los elementos de la lista de clientes preguntando si algún elemento de esta lista tiene la identificación igual al cliente que se está pasando como parámetro de ser igual se retorna **true**, si ninguno es igual se retorna **false**

Se llamaría así:

```
Cliente nuevoCliente = new Cliente(//parámetros del constructor);

if(ExisteCliente(nuevoCliente))
{
   //Ya existe
}
else
{
   //Se inserta
}
```

Comment: Solo un apunte, la variable `encontrado` no está declarada, por lo que tendrás errores de compilación. Debes usar `existe`.

Comment: Ademas, el tipo de dato `bool` no existe en Java, debe ser `boolean`.

Comment: Si gracias a los dos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes optar por utilizar `HashSet` en lugar de un `ArrayList`. Es una colección que representa un conjunto, que no permite elementos repetidos. Pero hay que hacer un par de implementaciones a nivel de la clase `Cliente`: sobreescribir los métodos `equals()` y `hashCode()`, para que el `HashSet` sepa cuándo un elemento a agregar ya ha sido agregado y evitar agregarlo nuevamente.

Código a agregar en la clase **Cliente**:

```
public class Cliente {
    private String nombre;
    private int identificacion;
    // Más atributos
    // Constructores
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // hay que asegurar que obj es de la clase Cliente
        if (obj != null && obj instanceof Cliente) {
            // se comparan los números de identificación
            Cliente another = (Cliente) obj;
            return this.identificacion == another.identificacion;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // Identificador único del objeto para colecciones HashSet, por ejemplo
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Se utilizará el número de identificación.
        return this.identificacion;
    }
    // Más código
}
```

Nuevo código:

```
public class AutoMovilesMejorado  {
    
    public BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    private Cliente cliente; 
    
    HashSet<Cliente> listaCliente = new HashSet();


        private void ingresarCliente() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Ingrese los datos separados por '&':(Nombre, Edad, Identificacion, Presupuesto)");
        String texto = br.readLine();
        String [] dato = texto.split("&");
        String nombre = dato[0];
        int edad = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
        int identificacion = Integer.parseInt(dato[2]);
        double presupuesto = Double.parseDouble(dato[3]);
        if (dato.length==4) {
        Cliente clienteNuevo = new Cliente(nombre,edad,identificacion,presupuesto, false);
        if (edad >= 18 ) {
                if (listaCliente.add(clienteNuevo)) { //Si devuelve true, significa que se agregó
                    System.out.println("Usuario Ingresado Correctamente " + "\n" + listaCliente);
                } else{
                    System.out.println("Identificacion repetida");
                }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Debe ser mayor de edad");
        }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Datos mal ingresados");
            ingresarCliente();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: me gusta como se ve, pero todavia no he visto hashSet, pero gracias de todas formas lo tendre en cuenta a futuro

Answer (score 0):

Asimilando un poco el problema pienso que lo mejor es lo siguiente, he comentado cada parte que me parece importante del código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
 static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            
 static ArrayList<Cliente> listaCliente = new ArrayList<Cliente>();
 static String Almacenador = "";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ingresarCliente();          

    
    }
        private static void ingresarCliente() throws IOException{
            System.out.println("Ingrese los datos separados por '&':(Nombre, Edad, Identificacion, Presupuesto)");
            String texto = br.readLine();
            String [] dato = texto.split("&");
            String nombre = dato[0];
            int identificacion = Integer.parseInt(dato[2]);
            double presupuesto = Double.parseDouble(dato[3]);
            int edad = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
            if (edad >= 18 ) {
            int tamanoArray = listaCliente.size(); // Verifico el tamaño de la lista
            
            while(tamanoArray > 0) { //Mientras el tamaño sea mayor a 0 verifique

                if(listaCliente.get(tamanoArray-1).identificacion == identificacion) { //Si en la posición la casilla de identificación es igual a la ingresada 
                    System.out.println("Ese identificación ya se encuentra registrada");
                    break; 
                }
                tamanoArray--; // en caso de no ser iguales pase al siguiente
                }
            if(tamanoArray == 0) { //Si el tamaño del array es 0 entonces ya verifico o es el primer elemento 


                    Cliente nuevocliente = new Cliente(nombre, edad, identificacion,presupuesto);
                     
                    listaCliente.add(nuevocliente);
                    
                    Almacenador += listaCliente.get(listaCliente.size()-1).toString(); 
                    System.out.println("Usuario Ingresado Correctamente " + "\n" + Almacenador); //Muestra todos los datos ingresados
                    }
     
                
        } else {
            System.out.println("Debe ser mayor de edad, por favor verifiquelo");
        }
       
            ingresarCliente(); //Llama el metodo de ingresar infinitamente
         }
        
    }
```

La clase cliente es la siguiente:

```
public class Cliente {

    public String nombre;
    public int edad;
    public int identificacion;
    public double presupuesto;
    public Cliente(String nombre2, int edad2, int identificacion2, double presupuesto2) {
        nombre = nombre2;
        edad = edad2;
        identificacion = identificacion2;
        presupuesto = presupuesto2;
    }
    
    
    
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Datos: ["+nombre + " "+edad+" " + " "+ identificacion+" "+ presupuesto +"] \n";
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `contains()` lo que hace es llamar al método `equals()` de la clase contenida en el `ArrayList`, en este caso, de la clase Cliente, y lo compara con el objeto cliente que le indiques.

Por lo tanto, en vez de pasarle como parámetro `contains(identificacion)`, deberías pasarle el objeto `clienteNuevo`.

Quedaría así:

```
if (listaCliente.contains(clienteNuevo)) {
    System.out.println("Identificacion repetida");  
}
```

**Aclaración**:

Si utilizas el método `contains()` sin modificar el método `equals()` de la clase Cliente, sólo devolverá true si TODOS sus atributos coinciden (nombre, edad, identificación, presupuesto).

Para personalizar el método `equals()` de la clase Cliente, para, por ejemplo, que interprete que dos clientes son iguales si, como mínimo, los identificadores coindicen, e ignorando los demás atributos, deberás hacer un [Override](https://www.arquitecturajava.com/java-override-y-encapsulacion/).

Tu clase Cliente quedaría así:

```
class Cliente {

    private int identificador;

    //el resto de atributos.

    //constructor

    //getters y setters.

    // AQUI EL OVERRIDE DE EQUALS.
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Cliente cliente) {
   
        // Esto es una forma resumida para hacer un if y un return en la misma linea.
        return this.identificador == cliente.getIdentificador();
    }
}
```

Además, el método contains ya retorna un boolean, por lo que es reduntante la comprobación `==true`.

Las demás respuestas también pueden funcionar, pero creo que esta es una forma más limpia de hacerlo.

Un saludo y que te sirva de ayuda!

Comment: en "private identificador;" , deberia seria un boolean o int, algo asi?

Comment: Normalmente es un int, no un boolean, y se le suele llamar id en vez de identificador.

Comment: "Si utilizas el método contains() sin modificar el método equals() de la clase Cliente, sólo devolverá true si TODOS sus atributos coinciden...": Esto es FALSO. La implementación del método `equals()` en la clase `Object` solo verifica que ambas referencias son iguales, o sea, si se trata del el mismo objeto.

Comment: Si no verificas que el parámetro `cliente` sea != `null` puedes tener un NPE al invocar el método `getIdentificador()`.